# Session in While Loop PHP

Tags: php, database, session, while-loop, overwrite

```
<form action="includes/xxx.php"  method="get">
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; 
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                ?> 
                    </td>

                <td><?php echo $row['length']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['value'];
                    $_SESSION['value'] = $row['value'];
                ?>
                    </td> 

                <td><input type="text" name="value" placeholder="XXX"></td> 

                <td><button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  OK </button> </td>
            </form>
```

In the upper code, I'm displaying my db table with a *while loop*

Each row has `ID`/`LENGTH`/`NAME`/`VALUE`/`INPUT`/`BUTTON`.

I get a value from the user, and I want to add it with the value in the same row and then update my db table.

GET method / displaying / SESSIONS and Update are done, but when I'm filling the input field the result saved in the last id.

I know that my code overwrites something and it can't understand what input I filled up.

How can I solved it?

Comment: Hi Can you explain a little more, I'm guessing you're in a rush. We  are not, but maybe we can answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use sessions this way. Add a separate hidden input box to send the ID to the server for processing.

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="value" placeholder="XXX">
</td>
```

Now when you submit the form you will have 2 values, `$_GET['row_id']` and `$_GET['value']`. Use the `row_id` to update the row you are trying to change.

If needed, you can still set the session values when you are processing the submitted form.

Comment: @ΠαύλοςΚουναβης Glad I could help.